# Are there "Lets" in table tennis?

Tags: rules, table-tennis, serve

In tennis if I serve the ball and it goes into the opposite service box, but hits the net on the way, it is a [let](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennis#Play_of_a_single_point).
Is there such a thing as a let in table tennis?

Answer (score 6):

The table-tennis version of a tennis 'let' is sometimes called a 'net.'  In general, a 'let' in table tennis is when the rally is stopped for some reason and no point is awarded.  Examples of Lets include

> 2.9.1.1 if in service the ball, in  passing over or around the net  assembly, touches it, provided the  service is otherwise good or the
>   ball  is obstructed by the receiver or  his/her partner;
>   2.9.1.2 if the service is delivered  when the receiving player or pair is  not ready, provided that neither the  receiver nor his/her partner
>   attempts  to strike the ball;
>   2.9.1.3 if failure to make a service or  a return or otherwise to comply with  the Laws is due to a disturbance  outside the control of
>   the player;
>   2.9.1.4 if play is interrupted by the  umpire or assistant umpire.
>   2.9.1.5 if the receiver is in a  wheelchair due to a physical  disability and the ball
>   2.9.1.5.1 after touching the receiver’s  court returns in the direction of the  net;
>   2.9.1.5.2 comes to rest on the  receiver's half;
>   2.9.1.5.3 in singles leaves the  receiver’s half after touching it by  either of its sidelines.

These are taken from the USA Table Tennis rules, but the ITTF rules are basically the same.

Comment: All these years I thought there weren't "let"s in table tennis, thanks!

Comment: +1 - You'll also find that a let in tennis is sometimes referred to as a "net service".